# XHR request on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, screen-scraping

Is it possible to perform an XHR request on google sheets and thus scrape the data which it calls upon? I am trying to scrape the table containing information about referee bookings from:

http://www.ligue1.com/LFPStats/stats_arbitre?competition=D1

I would like to present it in a useable format on google sheets.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You'll probably need to host a feed somewhere that scrapes the data, then import that into your sheet.

Comment: Ok I had done that but I was hoping that there might be a way to do it within the spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Use the IMPORTHTML function to scrape the data 
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en

Comment: to my understanding that function only works if the table or list is contained in the source code? In this case it is called by a http header and so is not present in the source code.